# How to determine maximum instantaneous rate of change on a cubic function when there are required gradient values

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to understand how to find the maximum rate of change when say there is a given gradient of the function. My cubic function is:

$$f(x) = -\frac{7}{4000}x^{3}+\frac{269}{400}x^{2}-\frac{1717}{20}x+3570 $$

Tnd the gradient needs to be between $-5$ and $5$. This is as far as I understand to find the gradient we differentiate the cubic then find the $x$ values for it and that gives us our gradient. When I do this I get value like x=130. This is the part that confuses me and I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is this a problem for a course? What is the exact wording of the problem definition?

Comment: Won't the maximum rate of change be reached when $f''(x)=0$?

Comment: The derivative is equal to
$$
f'(x) = \frac{-21x^2+5380x - 343~400}{4000}
$$
and if you want this to be between $-5$ and $5$, you get the equation
$$
-5 <\frac{-21x^2+5380x - 343~400}{4000} < 5
$$

Comment: Determine the maximum instantaneous rate of change on z (x). For safety reasons, the gradient cannot be more than 5 or less than -5. This will be easy to do once you have researched how to find the maximum gradient of a function.

Comment: @MattiP. Hopefully you are able to give me a hand with this